# MERGE statement in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, merge

I want to use merge statement in SSIS. I have one source (Oracle) and one destination (SQL Server). Both the tables and structure are same.

I need to insert, update and delete the data based on some date criteria. My question is should I use Merge Join or Lookup Table as I have more than 40 million records in Oracle.

If need more clarification let me know. I will provide you with more info. I am not good in posting though so forgive me.

Comment: How many records are in SQL Server?  How many columns of data in Oracle that will be needed for the calculations?

Comment: In Sql Server there are about 4 million records and 56 columns for past 1 year. In Oracle there are more than 150 columns with no indexing.

Comment: Do you need all the columns in Oracle for the calculations?

Comment: There are no calculations.. just copying the data from Oracle to Sql Server Using merge statement based on Date Criteria. from jan 1 2015 to Dec 31 2015 .if data not available then insert , if any change then update else delete from target table

Comment: I believe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488779/when-to-use-lookup-merge-join-transformation-in-ssis

Comment: I have used Merge join in the past and had indifferent results.  There are posts about how this isn't very reliable (I have seen legitimate joins missed).  Lookup component is fast and fine, as long as you have enough ram to read everything in.  Reducing the values via a select in here helps enormously over just selecting a table.  Also another excellent pointer an expert gave me was to minimise the processing in SSIS as much as possible and offload the hard work to the databases.  I usually try and get everything onto my SQL Server and perform merge statements in there if i can. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would transfer the oracle table to SQL Server and perform any operations locally.  I use this approach almost always (nothing quite to the size of your data) but its also useful when dealing with cloud based databases (latency, etc).  Its worth noting that if you don't have a datetime column in your source you can use the ORA_ROWSCN pseudo column which gives you a crude change set to load locally.

I have read lots of tales about Merge join not performing accurate joins - i would expect with data of your size it could be an issue.

Lookup could be an issue also due to the size as it has to cache everything (this would attempt to load all oracle records into SSIS anyway so better to transfer it locally).

Hope this helps :)